# Personal matters: Is my boss required to know?

Tags: management

We are allowed 5 call-ins a year at my place of employment, I am no where near that. I had to call in for a personal family matter.... Does my boss have the right to know what this matter is? Or can I opt to have some things remain personal?

Comment: Geography may matter here as I don't think I'm that familiar with the term "call in" over here in North American IT work.

Comment: What country are you working in?

Comment: @JB I've been in North American (Michigan, Ohio, Oregon, Alberta) and have heard the term 'call in' and 'phone in' occasionally. Usually as 'call in sick' but I think the point of this is that OP wants to keep the reason secret.

Answer (score 7):

In general, no - your boss does not have carte blanche insight into your personal matters, even when they intrude upon work. You'd need to check with the laws in your jurisdiction and the employee handbook (or equivalent) for your company to know for sure.

But in general, personal days or PTO need no explanation. Your boss may be curious about it, and even justifiably curious if it might recur and force you to take more time off. If you can let your boss know that it was a one-time thing (or not) without going into detail, I've personally found that to be the best compromise.

*Sick Time* on the other hand sometimes will require some matter of evidence to claim it. Again, check your local laws and policies.

Comment: Typically evidence for sick time is only required (by company policies) for more than 2 consecutive days.  I know of no laws requiring the notification in the US, then again that's a question for a lawyer.

Comment: @Foosh It's not that US laws would *require* notification or evidence, and rather that they might *allow an employer* to require notification or evidence where they would be prohibited from doing so under other circumstances.

Answer (score 2):

You should have every right to let certain things remain personal, the question is whether you want to.

In my workplace there was a case of a colleague taking up a lot of free days after one another, without ever telling us why. This colleague was really underperforming and seemed very unmotivated. We assumed he was taking these days off for job interviews at other companies. This made us all worry we were about to lose someone in our team. Even though we had never received any official signals that he was looking for a different job, people were already making arrangements in the background to replace him.

It turned out one of his children had been diagnosed with a serious condition and he had to take him to the hospital several times. When he told us, everyone was very supportive and my boss even offered him extra days off if he required them.

I have no insight into what your personal issue is (maybe you should clarify in your question?), but depending on it's nature you should opt to let your boss know why. It shows you trust him and he might even be able to help you out with things if need be. It helps when you see your superiors and colleagues as teammembers instead of people with rights, priviliges and duties.

If your boss and/or colleagues knowing about this personal issue would influence your relationship with them or make you feel uncomfortable, you should simply refrain from saying anything about it and explain them why.

Comment: I think one aspect of the workplace that is often forgotten is that it is a community.  *Usually* the people there honestly care about and are willing to help with problems their coworkers face.